# Why does my getColor function always return false?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets user input and its supposed to validate the user input from a list of options. The last part of the function, where I cycle through results and return true, if there's a true boolean value in results doesn't seem to be working properly. It keeps returning false.

```
    function getColor(){
        //gets user color and makes all characters lower case;
        let color=prompt("Pick a color, your options are white, yellow, brown, black, tan, red, orange").toLowerCase();

        //stores acceptable colors
        let acceptableColors=["white","yellow", "brown", "black","tan","red","orange"];

        function validate(){
            let results=[];
            for(let i=0; i<acceptableColors.length; i++){//loops through and stores a true value in results if user color is in list of acceptableColors
                    if(color===acceptableColors[i]){
                        results.push(true);
                    }
                    else{
                        results.push(false);
                    }

            }

            results.forEach(function(item){//loops through results to search for true value and returns true, if it finds one
                if(item===true){
                    return true
                }
            });
             return false;//returns false if user entered invalid color

        }
        return validate();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you push stuff to an object and then check for truthy values? Just use `return true;` in your condition and skip out on the `else` call.

Comment: *"Why does my getColor function always return false?"* -- because `validate()` always returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It keeps returning false.

`Return false` inside `forEach` will not return from `getColor` **and your return false is unconditional**

Make it

```
    return results.some(function(item){
       return item;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
function validate(){
        let results=[];
        for(let i=0; i<acceptableColors.length; i++){//loops through and stores a true value in results if user color is in list of acceptableColors
                if(color===acceptableColors[i]){
                    return true;
                }    
        }
        return false;//returns false if user entered invalid color

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing this way

```js
function validate() {
    return acceptableColors.indexOf(color) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole function can be simplified. There's no need to push booleans in an array, and then check that array for truthy values. Just use `includes` to check if the color array includes the user's prompted color.

```
function getColor() {
  let color = prompt("Pick a color, your options are white, yellow, brown, black, tan, red, orange").toLowerCase();
  let acceptableColors = ["white", "yellow", "brown", "black", "tan", "red", "orange"];
  return acceptableColors.includes(color);
}

getColor();
```

Comment: Be aware that [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does not work in any version of IE (unless you consider Edge). Use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead (supported by IE9+) or use a polyfill.

Comment: I actually didn't know that @h2ooooooo. Thanks for pointing that out.